# d3 stacked area graph not working with log scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have been able to put together a stacked area graph. 
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xhmphgw/7/), which uses dummy data. However, I want to implement the y axis as a logarithmic scale. But when I change the line

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([HEIGHT, 0]);
```

to

```
var y = d3.scale.log()
          .range([HEIGHT, 0]);
```

my graph stops rendering with errors like

> d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute
>   d="M0,NaNQ400,NaN,500,NaNQ600,NaN,1000,NaNL1000,NaNQ600,NaN,500,NaNQ400,NaN,0,NaNZ".

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on [*Log Scales*](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#log-scales):

> As log(0) is negative infinity, a log scale must have either an exclusively-positive or exclusively-negative domain; the domain must not include or cross zero.

You need to ensure that your domain does not include the zero value. Setting it to some small value will suffice:

```
y.domain([1e-6, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xhmphgw/8/) for a working example.